# query which do count missing some of the numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have procedure which should calculate count based on clients CategoryCode and ethnicity
looks like it working  but  it is missing some of the counts by category code 
This is procedure

```
alter PROCEDURE SelectTotalActiveClients
AS
declare @GrandTotal int 
set @GrandTotal = (select COUNT (clientID)from Clients where StatusID in (1,2))
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    with native_cte (cat, cnt)
    AS
    (
        select c.Category, count(e.EthnCode) 'Native'
        from Category c, Ethnicity e, Clients cl
        where cl.CategCode = c.CategCode
        and cl.EthnCode = e.EthnCode
        and e.EthnCode = 'N'
        and cl.StatusID in (1,2)
        group by c.Category
    ),
    asian_cte (cat, cnt)
    AS
    (
        select c.Category, count(e.EthnCode) 'Asian'
        from Category c, Ethnicity e, Clients cl
        where cl.CategCode = c.CategCode
        and cl.EthnCode = e.EthnCode
        and e.EthnCode = 'A'
        and cl.StatusID in (1,2)
        group by c.Category
    ),
    black_cte (cat, cnt)
    AS
    (
        select c.Category, count(e.EthnCode) 'Black'
        from Category c, Ethnicity e, Clients cl
        where cl.CategCode = c.CategCode
        and cl.EthnCode = e.EthnCode
        and e.EthnCode = 'B'
        and cl.StatusID in (1,2)
        group by c.Category
    ),
    pacific_cte (cat, cnt)
    AS
    (
        select c.Category, count(e.EthnCode) 'Pacific'
        from Category c, Ethnicity e, Clients cl
        where cl.CategCode = c.CategCode
        and cl.EthnCode = e.EthnCode
        and e.EthnCode = 'P'
        and cl.StatusID in (1,2)
        group by c.Category
    ),
    white_cte (cat, cnt)
    AS
    (
        select c.Category, count(e.EthnCode) 'White'
        from Category c, Ethnicity e, Clients cl
        where cl.CategCode = c.CategCode
        and cl.EthnCode = e.EthnCode
        and e.EthnCode = 'W'
        and cl.StatusID in (1,2)
        group by c.Category
    ),
    multy_cte (cat, cnt)
    AS
    (
        select c.Category, count(e.EthnCode) 'Multy'
        from Category c, Ethnicity e, Clients cl
        where cl.CategCode = c.CategCode
        and cl.EthnCode = e.EthnCode
        and e.EthnCode not IN ('N', 'A', 'B', 'P', 'W', '0')
        and cl.StatusID in (1,2)
        group by c.Category
    ),
    unknown_cte (cat, cnt)
    AS
    (
        select c.Category, count(e.EthnCode) 'Unknown'
        from Category c, Ethnicity e, Clients cl
        where cl.CategCode = c.CategCode
        and cl.EthnCode = e.EthnCode
        and e.EthnCode = '0'
        and cl.StatusID in (1,2)
        group by c.Category
    ),
        total_cte (cat, cnt)
    AS
    (
        select c.Category, count(e.EthnCode) 'Total'
        from Category c, Ethnicity e, Clients cl
        where cl.CategCode = c.CategCode
        and cl.EthnCode = e.EthnCode
        and cl.StatusID in (1,2)
        group by c.Category
    )
    SELECT  Category, native_cte.cnt 'Native', asian_cte.cnt 'Asian', 
            black_cte.cnt 'Black', pacific_cte.cnt 'Pacific', white_cte.cnt 'White', multy_cte.cnt 'Multy',
            unknown_cte.cnt 'Unknown', total_cte.cnt as 'Total'
    FROM    Category 
    left outer  JOIN native_cte on Category.Category = native_cte.cat
    left outer  JOIN asian_cte on native_cte.cat = asian_cte.cat
        left outer  join black_cte on asian_cte.cat = black_cte.cat
                left outer join pacific_cte on black_cte.cat = pacific_cte.cat
                    left outer join white_cte on pacific_cte.cat = white_cte.cat
                        left outer join multy_cte on white_cte.cat = multy_cte.cat
                             left outer join unknown_cte on multy_cte.cat = unknown_cte.cat
                                left outer join total_cte on unknown_cte.cat  = total_cte.cat
END
GO
```

it gives result:

```
Child     NULL  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
Infant    NULL  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
Newborn   NULL  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
Pregnant      2 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
Postpartum    1 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
Senior      220 188       36     11      485     12      44  996
```

however when i run this cte select by them selves it gives different respond 
for example

```
select c.Category, count(e.EthnCode) 'White'
        from Category c, Ethnicity e, Clients cl
        where cl.CategCode = c.CategCode
        and cl.EthnCode = e.EthnCode
        and e.EthnCode = 'W'
        and cl.StatusID in (1,2)
        group by c.Category

Postpartum  4
Pregnant    2
Senior      485
```

Please help me find the mistake in my query! Thank you

Comment: You are cascading your `LEFT JOIN`s. Is that intentional?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your entire query can be simplified as follows:

```
SELECT  c.Category,
        [Native] = COUNT(CASE WHEN cl.EthnCode = 'N' THEN cl.EthnCode END),
        [Asian] = COUNT(CASE WHEN cl.EthnCode = 'A' THEN cl.EthnCode END),
        [Black] = COUNT(CASE WHEN cl.EthnCode = 'B' THEN cl.EthnCode END),
        [Pacific] = COUNT(CASE WHEN cl.EthnCode = 'P' THEN cl.EthnCode END),
        [White] = COUNT(CASE WHEN cl.EthnCode = 'W' THEN cl.EthnCode END),
        [Multy] = COUNT(CASE WHEN cl.EthnCode NOT IN ('N', 'A', 'B', 'P', 'W', '0') THEN cl.EthnCode END),
        [Unknown] = COUNT(CASE WHEN cl.EthnCode = '0' THEN cl.EthnCode END),
        [Total] = COUNT(cl.EthnCode)
FROM    Category c, 
        LEFT JOIN Clients cl
            ON cl.CategCode = c.CategCode
            AND cl.StatusID IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY Category
```

This should yield the same results, should perform much better, and is (in my opinion) much more legible.

I can't see where you use `@GrandTotal` later in the query, but if you need a Total row at the bottom you can use [WITH ROLLUP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189305%28v=sql.90%29.aspx):

```
SELECT  [Category] = ISNULL(c.Category, 'Total'),
        [Native] = COUNT(CASE WHEN cl.EthnCode = 'N' THEN cl.EthnCode END),
        [Asian] = COUNT(CASE WHEN cl.EthnCode = 'A' THEN cl.EthnCode END),
        [Black] = COUNT(CASE WHEN cl.EthnCode = 'B' THEN cl.EthnCode END),
        [Pacific] = COUNT(CASE WHEN cl.EthnCode = 'P' THEN cl.EthnCode END),
        [White] = COUNT(CASE WHEN cl.EthnCode = 'W' THEN cl.EthnCode END),
        [Multy] = COUNT(CASE WHEN cl.EthnCode NOT IN ('N', 'A', 'B', 'P', 'W', '0') THEN cl.EthnCode END),
        [Unknown] = COUNT(CASE WHEN cl.EthnCode = '0' THEN cl.EthnCode END),
        [Total] = COUNT(cl.EthnCode)
FROM    Category c, 
        LEFT JOIN Clients cl
            ON cl.CategCode = c.CategCode
            AND cl.StatusID IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY Category
WITH ROLLUP;
```

Comment: I used grand total to calculate % from Total column

Comment: Thank you so much I spend 1 hour to looking on my query  but cennot find the error but your variant is so simple!

Comment: just fin out that tolal column calculation is in correct Child 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
Infant 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
Newborn 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
Postpartum 0 0 1 0 0 0 3 0
Pregnant 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
Senior 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1
Total 0 0 1 0 0 0 4 1

Comment: I noticed that I had missed the `white` column from my answer and had unknown as EthnCode = U not 0 so I've edited that, but I can't see any reason that the Total column would be lower than the sum of the other columns. I'd be happy to check though if you post some sample data on http://www.SQLFiddle.com

Comment: it is not lower it is higher :) I don't know why. Will submit later forget my laptop at home

Comment: Looks like it works right now :) I think iam just too tired :)

Answer (score 1):

try this, the left joins should be made with category :

```
FROM    Category 
left outer  JOIN native_cte on Category.Category = native_cte.cat
left outer  JOIN asian_cte on Category.Category = asian_cte.cat
left outer  join black_cte on Category.Category = black_cte.cat
left outer join pacific_cte on Category.Category = pacific_cte.cat
left outer join white_cte on Category.Category = white_cte.cat
left outer join multy_cte on Category.Category = multy_cte.cat
left outer join unknown_cte on Category.Category = unknown_cte.cat
left outer join total_cte on Category.Category  = total_cte.cat
```

Comment: it is working as it should be :) Thanx. so that means I have to join not table by table each time I have to join Category table?

Comment: You have to join based on your logic. There is no requirement for you to join adjacent tables. You can join as you want as long as the table you join on is previously defined.

Comment: OK I see Thanx so much :) they didn't teach us to this in college i learn this by my self but i think wasn't really understand how to use cte :)

Comment: In your case CTEs are just like normal temp tables. The same joining rules apply.